# Access fields from an http response by parsing the response

Tags: messagebroker, extended-sql

I got an XML Response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<List>
<type>MAILBOX</type>
<DOCS>
<DocId>39fece005f28qrn8000003r5</DocId>
<DocNo>123</DocNo>
</DOCS>
<DOCS>
<DocId>39fece005f28qrn8000003r6</DocId>
<DocNo>456</DocNo>
</DOCS>
</List>
```

I need to parse it so that I can use it and access DocId; what should be proper code to access docid?

Comment: Please share some comments or solution for my question . Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you want to do it in ESQL running in IIB? You should provide some more context. How does your flow look? What ESQL code you have so far?

Comment: Thanks for reply . Yes I want it in ESQL running in IIB(Broker Toolkit 9.0.0.4).I am placing a blank message in input node through RFH-Util. It is connected to HTTP request node via compute node where I have provided the URL. Next If response status is 200 I need to parse and list the DocId from the XML Response we are getting(XML response is shown in the question).I have tried many ways, I am geting the whole response but I cant access DocId. Please do reply and If any more clarification is required please comment back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up parsing on the HTTPRequest node, on the Response Message Parsing tab you select XMLNSC as the message domain, then on the output terminal you can use another Compute node and access the parts of the message as normal in ESQL, e.g.: InputBody.List.DOCS[1].DocId

Comment: Thank You Attila I can execute it now, Thanks for giving your time. It helped me lot to develop my concepts, I am new in this field, hope I will do better and help others thank you for your help.